# Call batch file with wildcard pattern

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm relatively new to batch scripts.

**The below command with * displays all matching files**

```
dir deploy*.bat
```

**But the same does not work with *call* command**

```
call deploy*.bat
```

It results in

> 'deploy*bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

**How can work this around?**

**Background:**
On a different groovy script, based on the parameter passed, I'm either deploying `deploy_sit.bat` or `deploy_uat.bat`. Irrespective of the file deployed, I want to be able to call the file `deploy*.bat`

Comment: `call` does not accept wildcards (obviously). For a workaround use a `FOR` loop or `FOR /F` with `dir`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Resolve-Path` cmdlet to do that:

```
call (Resolve-Path deploy*.bat).Path
```